Merging collinear sides (a.k.a. deleting collinear vertices) of a Polygon or LinearRing in Shapely
If two Polygons have partly overlapping sides, a union of these Polygons is a Polygon with collinear sides/vertices. Is there a method to merge those sides by deleting the middle vertex? I thought maybe normalize() method would do that but it does not.
p1 = sh.Polygon([(0,0),(1,0),(1,1),(0,1)])
p2 = sh.Polygon([(0,0),(2,0),(2,2)])
sum = shapely.union(p1,p2)

sum
<POLYGON ((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 2 2, 2 0, 1 0, 0 0))>   # the last 3 vertices are collinear
sum.normalize()
<POLYGON ((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 2 2, 2 0, 1 0, 0 0))>   # no change


Removing collinear points can be done using shapely.simplify.
Sample code:
import shapely as sh

p1 = sh.Polygon([(0,0),(1,0),(1,1),(0,1)])
p2 = sh.Polygon([(0,0),(2,0),(2,2)])
sum = sh.union(p1,p2)
sum_simplified = sh.simplify(sum, 0)

print(f"{sum=}")
print(f"{sum_simplified=}")

Output:
sum=<POLYGON ((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 2 2, 2 0, 1 0, 0 0))>
sum_simplified=<POLYGON ((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 2 2, 2 0, 0 0))>

